# JSON iOS failed Error

Tags: php, ios, json

So I have a web service that returns this JSON:

```
[{"other_user":"54","distance":"1 ft","duration":"1 min"},{"other_user":"55","distance":"2 ft","duration":"5 min"}]
```

Then in my ios app I use:

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSArray *responseArray = [responseString JSONValue];
    for (NSDictionary* item in responseArray) {
        NSString *otherUser = [item objectForKey:@"other_user"];
        NSString *otherDistance = [item objectForKey:@"distance"];
        NSString *otherDuration = [item objectForKey:@"duration"];

       NSLog(@"user: %@  distance: %@  time: %@", otherUser, otherDistance, otherDuration);
    }
```

but I am getting this error:

```
-JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [S]
```

Any help is appreciated, I have no Idea where to look/debug

Comment: Validate your JSON response (jsonlint.com) to see if its a valid JSON object. And Which JSON Parser are you using to parse the JSON response in your project ?

Comment: I am using SBJSON and it is valid

Comment: Print out `responseString`.  I'm guessing it's not valid JSON.

Comment: You're right, I had some echos in there. I feel stupid now. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

NSError *jsonError=nil;
NSArray *responseArray = [parser objectWithString: responseString error: &jsonError];

if (jsonError==nil) {
   for (NSDictionary* item in responseArray) {
      NSString *otherUser = [item objectForKey:@"other_user"];
      NSString *otherDistance = [item objectForKey:@"distance"];
      NSString *otherDuration = [item objectForKey:@"duration"];

      NSLog(@"user: %@  distance: %@  time: %@", otherUser, otherDistance, otherDuration);
   }
}
```

Good Luck

t

Comment: Tried this but apparently jsonError!=nil

Comment: then your json is probably invalid.

Comment: Yea, I guess I had some echos in the PHP that I didn't comment out after testing. which messed it up, it's working now. Thanks for your help